# Rails Migration: set locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have some migrations that import CSV into existing models (using `create!(..)`). Since I added some more validations, the migration breaks when executed:

```
Validation failed: Address translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.messages.is_invalid
```

We are using german as default language, so I'm a bit unsure why Rails looks for an english translation. We are using the rails-i18n gem.

```
# application.rb
config.i18n.default_locale = :de
config.i18n.available_locales = [:de, :en]
```

Anybody can tell me:

1) Why does Rails look for an english translation?
2) Why doesn't Rails find the english translation anyway?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To answer number 1, you need to set the locale first, setting the default locale does not do this :

```
config.i18n.locale = :de
```

Number 2 seems a bit stranger, but note that rails-i18n has only just recently included the base 'en' locale, previous it had 'en-US' and 'en-GB' and so on. It looks like you need to bump your rails-i18n version to 0.6.5 or higher.

Comment: Thank you, I did that in my application.rb, and now I'm getting proper german translations. Still, I already have v0.6.5, so why are the proper english translations missing? Is it because I have an empty en.yml file?